# Why the entity is not stored in the database?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, kotlin

I have two related faces. When saving to the database, only one object is successfully saved. The second one with a foreign key is not saved. The second one that has a foreign key is List  objects Please help.

here I added `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`, but it still did not work

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyOrder")
public class MyOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myOrder")
    private List<Products> productses;
```

I added fetch = Fetch.LAZY, that didn't help either.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Products {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_myorder_id")
    private MyOrder myOrder;
```

In the controller I fill it:

```
        MyOrder myOrder = new MyOrder();
        List<Products2> products2s =  object.getProductses2();
        List<Products> productses =  new ArrayList<Products>();
        for(int i =0;i<products2s.size();i++){
            Products2 products2 = products2s.get(i);
            Products products = new Products();

            products.setName(products2.getName());
            products.setWeight(products2.getWeight());
            products.setAmount(products2.getAmount());
            products.setPrice(products2.getPrice());
            productses.add(products);

        }
        myOrder.setProductses(productses);
        //saving
        serviceClass.createNewOrder(myOrder);
```

Service class :

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class MyServiceClass {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(value = "sessionFactory")
        SessionFactory session;



       public boolean createNewOrder(MyOrder myOrder){
            session.getCurrentSession().save(myOrder);
            return true;
        }

}
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `myorder` (
  `myOrder_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `myorder_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `myorder_courier_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`myOrder_id`),
  KEY `FK_q6alh4tjuhyudpq770duori5h` (`myorder_company_id`),
  KEY `FK_lcjnn2172xke45f2gmsiyvtep` (`myorder_courier_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_lcjnn2172xke45f2gmsiyvtep` FOREIGN KEY (`myorder_courier_id`) REFERENCES `courier` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_q6alh4tjuhyudpq770duori5h` FOREIGN KEY (`myorder_company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consignation` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `debt` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rec_price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `returned` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_categories_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_myorder_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ovaxmqou7gnwgchnhbkp9tq1p` (`product_categories_id`),
  KEY `FK_kwu6gyind0d2bthu19fcrkkcf` (`product_company_id`),
  KEY `FK_jeh86q0ligae6ggjlq9lq89y5` (`product_myorder_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_jeh86q0ligae6ggjlq9lq89y5` FOREIGN KEY (`product_myorder_id`) REFERENCES `myorder` (`myOrder_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_kwu6gyind0d2bthu19fcrkkcf` FOREIGN KEY (`product_company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ovaxmqou7gnwgchnhbkp9tq1p` FOREIGN KEY (`product_categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: an you please let me know in which entity you added **cascade = CascadeType.ALL**

Comment: On myorder,here:                                                             
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myOrder",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Products> productses;

Comment: Just tried the other way, added a cascade in Products. It didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You changes are not being cascaded from parent to child entity, you need to add it into your mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyOrder")
public class MyOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myOrder", cascade = CascadeType.All)
    private List<Products> productses;
```

With the column name error try this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "myorder_id")
private MyOrder myOrder;
```

Comment: I tried your code, got an error : Root Cause

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'myOrder_id' doesn't have a default value
 com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1094)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4226)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4158)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
 com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
 com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2840)

Comment: I guess you did not specify column name exactly, I'll edit the answer. But this is some other kind of error. You can see, that the one in question is solved - children are being saved.

Comment: Renaming id didn't work.The exception has disappeared, but only MyOrder is saved

Comment: I deleted the tables and started the project again, everything was saved. Only the foreign key of Products is empty(null). As if there is no connection.

Comment: Thank you very much. It remains to solve the problem with the external key.

Comment: Try to set it in for loop for each `Product`: `product.setMyOrder(myOrder)`

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the following mapping:

- use Long for id column, not int - int is too small
- Bidirectional mapping is probably better
- have Utility methods for adding/removing children (as in the code below)
- initialize your collections in the Entity classes to avoid nulls

Example:

```
@Entity(name = "MyOrder")
@Table(name = "myorder")
public class MyOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "myorder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    //Constructors, getters, setters etc.

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.add(product);
        product.setMyOrder(this);
    }

    public void removeProduct(Product product) {
        products.remove(product);
        product.setMyOrder(null);
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Product")
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "myorder_id")
    private MyOrder myOrder;

    //Constructors, getters and setters

    //equals and hashCode
}
```

Comment: nice, comprehensive list of improvements